# Access column names from reactive table for formatting with DT package

Tags: r, shiny, dt

I am trying to format a reactive table in a shiny app and display it with the DT package. There are many examples on how to do this with a non-reactive table such as: https://rstudio.github.io/DT/010-style.html. But when I try to use output from a reactive function in the same manner, I get a columns name error. Here is an example:

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)


ui <- fluidPage(
  fluidRow(
    column(3,numericInput("nrows","Enter the number of rows",value=10)),
    column(9,DT::dataTableOutput("table"))
  )
)
server <- function(input, output, session) {

  cars2 <- reactive({
    cars <- datasets::cars
    cars2 <- cars[1:input$nrows,]
    return(cars2)
  })

  output$table <- DT::renderDataTable(cars2()%>% formatStyle( 'speed',backgroundColor = c('yellow')),options=list(pageLength=50))


}


shinyApp(ui=ui,server=server)
```

And here is the error

```
Warning: Error in name2int: You specified the columns: speed, but the column names of the data are 
Stack trace (innermost first):
    94: name2int
    93: appendFormatter
    92: formatColumns
    91: formatStyle
    90: function_list[[k]]
    89: withVisible
    88: freduce
    87: _fseq
    86: eval
    85: eval
    84: withVisible
    83: %>%
    82: exprFunc
    81: widgetFunc
    80: func
    79: origRenderFunc
    78: renderFunc
    77: origRenderFunc
    76: output$table
     1: runApp
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works:

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {

  cars2 <- reactive({

    cars <- datasets::cars
    cars2 <- cars[1:input$nrows,]
    return(cars2)

  })

  output$table <- renderDataTable({

    datatable(cars2(), options = list(pageLength = 50)) %>%
      formatStyle('speed', backgroundColor = 'yellow')

  })

}
```

Comment: Thanks! In my actual app I need to keep the reactive table separate for use later on. I can get this to work in the example, but I just tried this in my app and I get the same columns name error. Any thoughts on what else could be going on?

Comment: Updated my code above to incorporate your comments.

Comment: @user29609 - Re-think loading `cars` in the beginning of your app.

Comment: Thank you, I restarted R and this example works in my actual app now!

Comment: Reactive variable needs to be called as a function. For instance, `cars2` will be accessible using `cars2()`. Similarly its columns will be accessed using `cars2()$speed` and so on.